# EJB TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) doesn'

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

I encountered an odd EJB transaction attribute problem. The @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) doesn't start a new transaction as expected.

I am using EJB 3 with Weblogic.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
@Stateless
public class EJB1 implements IEJB1
{
   @EJB 
   private IEJB2 ejb2;

   @Override
   public void method1()
   {
     for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
         ejb2.method2();
      }
   }
}

@Stateless
public class EJB2 implements IEJB2
{
   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public void method2()
   {
     DBpersist();
   }
}
```

Since I specified TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW for EJB2.method2, I expect a new transaction to be created for methood2. But during testing I found out there's no new transaction created for method2, instead method2 has the same transaction as EJB1.method1. I used Weblogic's API to log the transaction info.

I then made the following code change:

```
@Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED
public void method1()
{    
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
    ejb2.method2();
    }
}
```

This way it forced the container to create a new transaction for EJB2.method2.

But I don't understand why the container didn't create new transaction for EJB2.method2 when I had default TransactionAttributeType for EJB1.method1 (by not specifying any TransactionAttributeType) and TransactionAttributeType=REQUIRES_NEW for EJB2.method2.

I searched the existing questions related to this question. But all I found were the cases when you call a private method(with REQUIRES_NEW) from another private method within the same EJB, the container won't start a new transaction unless you call it through the EJB interface. This is not my case.

Comment: can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Hi Michael, you mean to provide the example code that can be compiled?

Comment: are  the interfaces annotated with @Local @Remote?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, they are annotated with @Remote

Comment: I can see an ´@Override´ annotation in method1() that doesn't make sense, It seems to be that are inheritances that are not present in your pseudo code, you need to provide a more accurate/complete code, If the bean class has superclasses additional rules apply to ´@TransactionAttribute´, maybe you are facing an issue of this kind

Comment: As NOT_SUPPORTED "helped" to actually force the creation of a new transactions also means that there actually was a running transaction already (perhaps created by an EJB Client). Are you sure you didn't accidentally measure this one as used of the whole time?

Comment: Did you try this approach: `@Stateless
public class EJB1 implements IEJB1
{
   @EJB 
   private IEJB2 ejb2;

   @Override
   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public void method1()
   {
     for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
         ejb2.method2();
      }
   }
}` ? This should also rollback your database in case there has been an error during one call of method2. You also have to remove the @TransactionAttribute annotation from method2.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo code looks ok. This has been practiced by me in various projects so there is nothing wrong.

There might be various causes for this

- Bug in the used weblogic version either in the interpretation of the transactionattribute inside REQUIRES or when injecting @EJB
- Bug in usage of the transaction info api